# Extends Strings Class Functions without inheritance

Tags: string, vb.net, oop

I am thinking to extends the *strings* functions and add my own functions to the module. but I found that the strings class is non-inheritable.

is there any way to extends the class. I found something like :

```
Class MyStringType
    Dim str As String
   function toTitleCase()
     'return titlecae
   end function
End Class

Dim s As MyStringType 
s.str = "mystringgoeshere"
```

but this does not extends in the proper way, it will results to :

```
S.Str.normalStringFunctions
S.MyOwnFunctionsHere
```

in result, the functions are not in the same level !!

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) also in VB.NET

```
Module MyExtensions

    <Extension()> 
    Public Sub toTitleCase(input As String)
        ....
    End Sub
End Module
```

After this 'syntactic sugar' is in place you can write your code as

```
Dim newString = oldString.toTitleCase()
```

However, I would to remember you that ToTitleCase method is already available in the [System.Globalization.TextInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace

Answer (score 0):

What you're after are [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).

Basically, you cannot extend `System.String`, but you can create subs or functions in modules and have the compiler "fake" they are string methods.